# What is the augmentation ideal of $\Bbb{Z}S_3$

Tags: ring-theory, group-rings

I know that $\Delta_{\Bbb{Z}}(G)$ is the $\Bbb{Z}-$ module generated by elements of form $\{g-1\ \forall\ g\in G\}$. But how do we find them or what it looks like.

I was thinking about finding aug ideal of $\Bbb{Z}S_3$ i.e. $\Delta({S_3})$ and then finding all its powers and what their intersection looks like.

I know that for solvable finite groups $\cap_{i}\Delta^{i}(G)=0$ by a theorem of Roggenkamp.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are looking for. Elements of the augmentation ideal look like $\sum_g a_g g$, where $\sum_g a_g=0$. It has basis $\{g-1\mid g\in G\backslash\{1\}\}$. You can write them out for $G=S_3$ if you like, but I don't know what you expect to gain from this exercise.

Comment: Also, in your last sentence, is the intersection $\cap_i\Delta(G^{(i)})$ where $G^{(0)}=G$ and $G^{(i)}=[G^{(i-1)},G^{(i-1)}]$ for $i>0$? Or is it $\cap_i\Delta(G)^i$?